# properties file from dependent spring project

Tags: java, spring

I have created two spring projects, and facing issue while using one project from the other.

in the first project, I have one properties file, and initializing a bean with these properties by defining them in the applicationContext.xml file.

in the other project, I have added this jar onto the build path. and when trying to access those properties it shows "Not enough variable values available to expand". I understand the context of the first project is not yet initialized.

But how should I initialize them from the second project? should I import the context file of the first project into the second? What should I do if I have to build a fully functional first project, without worrying about importing and all such stuffs?

Regards
ArunDhaJ

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the set up of two projects , is first project artifact a jar ? is second one a war/or a jar, any other additional info can only help.

Comment: Yes, first one is a jar and the second one is a war.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP i infer that the xml files and properties are part of the jar.

**Perform following checks on the jar file**
 - Check if xml and property files are included 
 - They should be in the root path.

Now in the war refer to the xml files/ property files as

```
 classpath:file.xml
```